# Reference between two classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code. Problem is I need access from class `Database` to class `MainWindow`. I tried to inherit in `Database` from `MainWindow` but it didnt work. I just need to have reference in both classes to each other class.
Thanks for any advice!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Database db = new Database(@"database.txt");

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setLabel(string s) 
    {
        Vystup.Content = s;
    }
}

class Database 
{
   //constructor and other methods

   public void doSomething()
   {
       //Here I want to set Label in MainWindow, something like
       //MainWindow.setLabel("hello");
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to pass MainWindow as a constructor parameter of Database class

Comment: **Do not do that.** This breaks SoS (Separation of Concerns) and encapsulation (*keep a classes private state private*). Your database class should do its work and return a result. Your MainWindow class should then update it's own label. Do not share private state between classes.

Comment: Just have Database take an object of type MainWindow in its constructor, and pass thet to a private field. Pass in 'this' with any other arguments you have. Then you can access it in Database. Better to use an interfaced object so you aren't tied to the actual MainWindow. @Igor is correct in this case though, this is purely how to do it - not that you should here...

Comment: @StevePadmore That's a *really* awful idea, for the reasons Igor has mentioned and then some.

Comment: @Igor I needed write error message when soubor "database.txt" do not exists. So you think better way is return false (or something similar)  to MainWindow and there in MainWindow update my label?

Comment: I was demonstrating how to do it. I also agreed with @Igor if you check my comment...

Comment: you can always use an out parameter of the data type string to return the value you put into your label: public void doSomething(out String statusText) {statusText = "your string";}

Comment: @StevePadmore If you know that it's a really bad idea to do that, then why tell the OP to do that?  Just describe how to do it *appropriately*.

Comment: Noted. Will ensure I don't do that again.

Comment: You should just check that the file exists in MainWindow before creating the Database object with the provided file if that's why you're setting the label text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this...

- Passing a reference of MainWindow to Database in Database's constructor. This is not recommended because then Database is dependent on MainWindow.
- Have the database function return the value that needs to be set whenever MainWindow has the Database do something.
- Passing an Action in the Database constructor for it to invoke when doSomething is called.

---

Passing a reference (not recommended)...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    Database db = new Database(this, @"database.txt");
    public void setLabel(string s) {
        Vystup.Content = s;
    }
}

class Database {
    private MainWindow _mainWindow { get; set; }
    public Database(MainWindow window, string file) {
        this._mainWindow = window;
        ...
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        _mainWindow.setLabel("hello");
    }
}
```

Database returns value to be set...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    Database db = new Database(@"database.txt");
    public void setLabel(string s) {
        Vystup.Content = s;
    }
    public void SomeDatabaseThing()
    {
        string returnValue = db.doSomething();
        setLabel(returnValue);
    }
}

class Database {
    public Database(string file) {
        ...
    }
    public string doSomething() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Passing Action in constructor...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    Database db = new Database(@"database.txt", setLabel);
    public void setLabel(string s) {
        Vystup.Content = s;
    }
}

class Database {
    private Action<string> _onDoSomething = null
    public Database(string file, Action<string> onDoSomething) {
        this._onDoSomething = onDoSomething;
        ...
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        onDoSomething("hello");
    }
}
```